# Angular/Material mat-form-field custom component - matSuffix in ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-material

My idea was to have basic component providing some functionality and  add `matSuffix` and `<mat-hint>` options as necessary. The component HTML is:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="1" matAutosizeMaxRows="3"
    [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControl]="inputField"></textarea>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-form-field>
```

However when I am using this in parent HTML template as

```
<my-component ...>
  <button matSuffix ...><mat-icon>something</mat-icon></button>
  <mat-hint>Press Ctrl+Enter to finish input</mat-hint>
</my-component>
```

The button and hint is rendered inside `mat-form-field` and not as suffix or hint.

Anyone, please?

Edit: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wywqpq)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The selector based children of MatFormField need to be direct children - they can not be nested inside other components. As an alternative, you can do something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="1" matAutosizeMaxRows="3"
    [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControl]="inputField"></textarea>
  <span matSuffix>
    <ng-content select="[suffix]"></ng-content>
  </span>
  <mat-hint>
    <ng-content select="[hint]"></ng-content>
  </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>

...

<my-component ...>
  <span suffix><button><mat-icon>something</mat-icon></button></span>
  <span hint>Press Ctrl+Enter to finish input</span>
</my-component>
```

Comment: Instead of using span to put the matSuffix directive on you could also use ng-container, this will not wrap your projected content in another span (which might mess up your styling).