# Display Angular Material mat-error in wrapper

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I properly display `<mat-error>` in a container without breaking the layout?

The background is this: I use a lot of basic validators in my template driven forms (`required`, `minlength`, `pattern) and want to display the corresponding error message.`mat-form-field`only supports the display of one`mat-error` at a time, and for every message I need to display a human readable error message. So every input will look something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput required minlength="4" pattern="…">
  <mat-error *ngIf="field?.errors?.required">Field is required</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="field?.errors?.minlength">Must be at least {{ field!.errors!.minlength.requiredLength }} characters</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="field?.errors?.pattern">Does not match pattern {{ … }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have to do this for every field. Seems pretty redundant!

I have tried several approaches for extracting this pattern from the template:

- Component
- `*ngFor`
- `<ng-container>`
- `<ng-template>`

However, they all mess up the layout, the error is then sort of displayed within the input field. I assume the issue is that `mat-error` needs to be a direct descendant of `mat-form-field` and all my approaches add an extra element between `mat-error` and `mat-form-field`.

So how can I handle errors without having to write all the `mat-error` lines for every input?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to `<mat-error>{{ getError() }}</mat-error>`. then handle logic in your component ? more over, you can pass the `field` object to your getError() method, and have it a generic one for all inputs.

Comment: Try this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574642/angular-material-mat-form-field-custom-component-matsuffix-in-ng-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are using the template driven approach, I tend to go for the Reactive one for any forms that don't class as really simple.

The method used should be made generic, passing in the field. I have used a single use-case for clarity

Typescript class:

```
get email() {
   return this.form.get('email');
}

 getEmailError() {
    return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter an email address' :
    this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
}
```

Template file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    type="email"
    matInput
    placeholder="Your Email"
    autocomplete="false"
    formControlName="email">
  <mat-hint>Please enter an email address</mat-hint>
  <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getEmailError()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I don't know why but using mat-error in this way causes multiple and I mean more than 100 calls to method, slowing down the processing and eventually giving the user where he feels the system has hanged

Comment: Be careful, binding a function in templates causes the function to be called for every changeDetect cycle.

Comment: You can switch your component's change detection strategy to `onPush` but you have to be clever about triggering change detection when necessary.  The good news is that just using `formControl` / `formControlName` will ensure that CD runs when control value or validity changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput required minlength="4" pattern="…">

<mat-error *ngfor="let type of (validationTypes$ | async)">
  <mat-error *ngIf="field?.errors[type]">{{validationMessagesService.getValidatorErrorMessage(type, maxLength, 'fieldName')}}</mat-error>
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This solved my problem. No idea why you got the down votes.

Comment: Solved it for me as well, feels "hacky" to use this, but much better than a function call in the template in my opinion.